# Type checking json values when unmarshaling in Go

Tags: json, go

I'm working with an API that usually provides json  string values but they will sometimes provide numbers instead. For example, 99% of the time it's like this:

```json
{
    "Description": "Doorknob",
    "Amount": "3.25"
}
```

But for whatever reason, sometimes it's like this:

```json
{
    "Description": "Lightbulb",
    "Amount": 4.70
}
```

Here is the struct I'm using which works in 99% of the time:

```golang
type Cart struct {
    Description string `json:"Description"`
    Amount      string `json:"Amount"`
}
```

But it'll break when they provide a numeric amount. What's the best way to type check when unmarshaling a struct?

playground: https://play.golang.org/p/S_gp2sQC5-A

Comment: Do you need to type check, or you you need to accept both? `json.Number` will accept a string or numeric value.

Comment: I second JimB's suggesion https://play.golang.org/p/QL5xvzI8Zmh (here's the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Number))

Comment: @JimB I can't believe I haven't seen this. Great suggestion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the general case you may use `interface{}` as described in [Burak Serdar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63853050/1705598).

For numbers specifically, there's the [`json.Number`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Number) type: it accepts both JSON numbers and JSON strings, and it can "automatically" parse the number if it's given as string with [`Number.Int64()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Number.Int64) or [`Number.Float64()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Number.Float64). No custom marshalers / unmarshalers are required.

```
type Cart struct {
    Description string      `json:"Description"`
    Amount      json.Number `json:"Amount"`
}
```

Testing it:

```
var (
    cart1 = []byte(`{
    "Description": "Doorknob",
    "Amount": "3.25"
}`)

    cart2 = []byte(`{
    "Description": "Lightbulb",
    "Amount": 4.70
}`)
)

func main() {
    var c1, c2 Cart
    if err := json.Unmarshal(cart1, &c1); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", c1)
    if err := json.Unmarshal(cart2, &c2); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", c2)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/HWlGf0_pBb0)):

```
{Description:Doorknob Amount:3.25}
{Description:Lightbulb Amount:4.70}
```

Answer (score 1):

If that field can be a string or int, you can use an interface{}, and then figure out the underlying value:

```
type Cart struct {
    Description string `json:"Description"`
    Amount      interface{} `json:"Amount"`
}

func (c Cart) GetAmount() (float64,error) {
  if d, ok:=c.Amount.(float64); ok {
     return d,nil
  }
  if s, ok:=c.Amount.(string); ok {
     return strconv.ParseFloat(s,64)
  }
  return 0, errors.New("Invalid amount")
}
```